# Formatting longtable to width of landscape page

Tags: longtable, landscape

I'm having trouble formatting the following table to be a landscape page width as well as span multiple pages. I think my issue might be font size and change of column width but I can't seem to fix either of these things. I have checked out all the relevant questions but could use a bit of help with my specific example. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry, amssymb, amsmath, setspace, rotating, titlesec, multirow, adjustbox, array, booktabs, threeparttable, longtable, lscape}
\geometry{verbose,letterpaper,tmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.54cm,lmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm} 

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
 >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
 l%
 <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{45}{1em}}}% no optional argument here, please!

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth} % default: 4in (rather less than \textwidth...)
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \parindent
\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{5}{ccrrlllllllllllllll}}
\caption{...} \\
\textbf{Year}&\textbf{Region}&\textbf{Beetle Family}&\textbf{Beetle Species}&\rot{\textbf{Total Beetles (Mites)}}&\rot{\textbf{Total Mite Species}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Iponemus confusus} Lindquist}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Dendrolaelaps neodisetus} (Hurlbutt)}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{D. quadrisetus} (Berlese)}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Ereynetes propescutulis} Hunter}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Paracarophaenax} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Tarsonemus} spp.$^1$}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Elattoma} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiogaster arborsignis} Woodring}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma} spp.$^2$}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma anops}}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Trichouropoda australis} Hirschmann}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Proctolaelaps} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{Unidentified}} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\textbf{Year}&\textbf{Region}&\textbf{Beetle Family}&\textbf{Beetle Species}&\rot{\textbf{Total Beetles (Mites)}}&\rot{\textbf{Total Mite Species}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Iponemus confusus} Lindquist}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Dendrolaelaps neodisetus} (Hurlbutt)}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{D. quadrisetus} (Berlese)}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Ereynetes propescutulis} Hunter}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Paracarophaenax} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Tarsonemus} spp.$^1$}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Elattoma} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiogaster arborsignis} Woodring}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma} spp.$^2$}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma anops}}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Trichouropoda australis} Hirschmann}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Proctolaelaps} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{Unidentified}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\small
2013&GA&Cerambycidae&\textit{Monochamus titallator} (Fabricius)&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Monochamus scutellatus} LeConte&2(20)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0.5(20)&0&0 \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Rhagium inquisitor}&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Xylotrechus} sp. Chevrolat&1(200)&5&0&0&0&1(1)&0&0&0&1(92)&0&0&0&0&1(107) \\
2013&GA&Cleridae&\textit{Enoclerus ichneumoneus} (Fabricius)&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Enoclerus nigrifrons} (Say)&4(1)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0.25(1)&0&0&0&0&0 \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Thanasimus dubius$^4$} Fabricius&21(91)&14&0.1(2)&0.14(3)&0&0.05(1)&0&0.05(1)&0&0.57(3.08)&0.24(1.8)&0.05(6)&0.05(1)&0&0.05(6) \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Thanasimus dubius} Fabricius&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Thanasimus dubius} Fabricius&17(131)&4&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0.29(21)&0.29(2.8)&0&0.18(4)&0&0 \\
2013&GA&Colydiinae&\textit{Lasconotus} sp. Erichson&3(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&Cossoninae&\textit{Cossonus} sp. Clairville&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&Curculionidae&\textit{Anthonomus} sp. Germar&1(2)&3&1(1)&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(1)&0&0&0&0&0 \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Dendroctonus brevicomis$^3$} LeConte&137(152)&10&0.01(1)&0&0&0&0.04(3.6)&0.22(3.07)&0.05(2.86)&0&0&0&0.03(1.5)&0&0.01(1) \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Dendroctonus frontalis} Zimmermann&36(48)&6&0.06(4.5)&0&0&0&0.03(1)&0.19(2)&0.17(3.33)&0&0&0&0&0.03(1)&0 \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Dendroctonus} sp. Erichson&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Dendroctonus valens} LeConte&1(15)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(15)&0&0&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Dendroctonus valens} LeConte&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Dendroctonus valens} LeConte&55(118)&6&0.02(2)&0&0&0&0&0&0&0.02(1)&0.35(4.42)&0&0.04(3.5)&0.09(4.4)&0 \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Dendroctonus valens} LeConte&1(2)&3&0&0&1(1)&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(1)&0&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Dryocetes autographus} (Ratzeburg)&3(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Dryopthorus americanus} Bedel&5(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Dryopthorus americanus} Bedel&4(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Dryopthorus americanus} Bedel&2(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Gnathotrichus materarius} Bedel&2(3)&2&0&0&0.5(2)&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Hylastes porculus} Erichson&1(1)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(1)&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Hylastes porculus} Erichson&47(16)&6&0&0&0&0&0&0.02(2)&0&0.04(1)&0.04(1)&0&0&0&0.02(1) \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Hylastes porculus} Erichson&3(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Hylobius} sp. Germar&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Ips avulsus} (Eichhoff)&239(2886)&9&0.23(2.57)&0.02(1)&0&0&0&0.16(2.03)&0.6(17.78)&0(1)&0.02(4.5)&0&0.13(1.44)&0(1)&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Ips calligraphus} (Germar)&1(36)&3&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(35)&0&1(1)&0&0&0&0 \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Ips grandicollis} (Eichhoff)&11(194)&5&0.45(17.8)&0&0.18(3)&0&0&0&0.55(16)&0&0&0&0.09(2)&0&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Ips grandicollis} (Eichhoff)&35(407)&7&0.29(2.2)&0&0&0&0&0.06(2.5)&0.26(20.44)&0.03(1)&0.37(12.92)&0&0.17(4.5)&0&0 \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Ips grandicollis} (Eichhoff)&10(189)&6&0.8(4.12)&0&0.2(3.5)&0&0&0.1(1)&0&0&0.5(21.4)&0&0.1(40)&0&0 \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Ips pini} (Say)&222(4688)&14&0.44(14.05)&0.02(1.75)&0.23(3.56)&0.07(1.75)&0.01(1.33)&0.08(2.44)&0.65(19.91)&0.02(10.8)&0.05(1.83)&0&0.21(2.07)&0.01(1)&0(1) \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Ips pini} (Say)&51(901)&11&0.33(4.76)&0&0&0.02(4)&0&0.14(2.86)&0.76(19.95)&0.02(1)&0.02(1)&0&0.08(1)&0.02(1)&0.04(1) \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Ips pini} (Say)&20(203)&7&0.3(27)&0&0.25(3.4)&0&0&0&0&0&0.25(3)&0&0.25(1.2)&0&0.1(1.5) \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Orthotomicus caelatus} (Eichhoff)&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Pachylobius picivorus} (Germar)&15(215)&5&0&0&0.07(4)&0&0&0&0&0&0.07(1)&0.2(53.67)&0&0.07(49)&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Pityopthorus} sp. Eichhoff&2(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Rhyncolus} sp. Germar&&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Xylosandrus} sp. Reitter&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&Elateridae&\textit{Ampedus} sp. Germar&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Melanotus} sp.&1(7)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(7)&0&0&0&0 \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Platysoma cylindrica}&4(7)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(1.75)&0&0&0&0 \\
2011&WI&Tenebrionidae&\textit{Corticeus parallelus} (Melsheimer)&5(41)&6&0.4(1.5)&0&0.2(16)&0&0&0&0&0&0.8(5)&0&0.2(1)&0.2(1)&0 \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Corticeus parallelus} (Melsheimer)&1(1)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(1)&0&0&0&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Hymenorus} sp.&3(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Hymenorus} sp.&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Isomira} sp. Mulsant&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&AZ&Trogossitidae&\textit{Temnocheila} sp. Westwood&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&Zopheridae&\textit{Lasconotus} sp. Erichson&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Namunaria} sp.&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\ \hline
&&&Total Beetle Species Carrying&--&--&9&3&6&3&3&7&7&9&12&3&9&6&5 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`longtable` can not work miracles. You can make it fit on a page but you can not make it readable. I think you need to rethink the table layout.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry, amssymb, amsmath, setspace, rotating, titlesec, multirow, adjustbox, array, booktabs, threeparttable, longtable, lscape}
\geometry{verbose,letterpaper,tmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.54cm,lmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm} 

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
 >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
 l%
 <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{45}{1em}}}% no optional argument here, please!

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth} % default: 4in (rather less than \textwidth...)
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \parindent
\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill
\tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll>{\raggedright}p{2cm}lllllllllllllll@{}}
\caption{...} \\
\textbf{Year}&\textbf{Region}&\textbf{Beetle Family}&\textbf{Beetle Species}&\rot{\textbf{Total Beetles (Mites)}}&\rot{\textbf{Total Mite Species}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Iponemus confusus} Lindquist}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Dendrolaelaps neodisetus} (Hurlbutt)}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{D. quadrisetus} (Berlese)}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Ereynetes propescutulis} Hunter}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Paracarophaenax} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Tarsonemus} spp.$^1$}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Elattoma} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiogaster arborsignis} Woodring}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma} spp.$^2$}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma anops}}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Trichouropoda australis} Hirschmann}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Proctolaelaps} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{Unidentified}} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\textbf{Year}&\textbf{Region}&\textbf{Beetle Family}&\textbf{Beetle Species}&\rot{\textbf{Total Beetles (Mites)}}&\rot{\textbf{Total Mite Species}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Iponemus confusus} Lindquist}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Dendrolaelaps neodisetus} (Hurlbutt)}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{D. quadrisetus} (Berlese)}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Ereynetes propescutulis} Hunter}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Paracarophaenax} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Tarsonemus} spp.$^1$}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Elattoma} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiogaster arborsignis} Woodring}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma} spp.$^2$}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma anops}}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Trichouropoda australis} Hirschmann}}&\rot{\textbf{\textit{Proctolaelaps} sp.}}&\rot{\textbf{Unidentified}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\small
2013&GA&Cerambycidae&\textit{Monochamus titallator} (Fabricius)&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Monochamus scutellatus} LeConte&2(20)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0.5(20)&0&0 \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Rhagium inquisitor}&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Xylotrechus} sp. Chevrolat&1(200)&5&0&0&0&1(1)&0&0&0&1(92)&0&0&0&0&1(107) \\
2013&GA&Cleridae&\textit{Enoclerus ichneumoneus} (Fabricius)&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Enoclerus nigrifrons} (Say)&4(1)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0.25(1)&0&0&0&0&0 \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Thanasimus dubius$^4$} Fabricius&21(91)&14&0.1(2)&0.14(3)&0&0.05(1)&0&0.05(1)&0&0.57(3.08)&0.24(1.8)&0.05(6)&0.05(1)&0&0.05(6) \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Thanasimus dubius} Fabricius&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Thanasimus dubius} Fabricius&17(131)&4&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0.29(21)&0.29(2.8)&0&0.18(4)&0&0 \\
2013&GA&Colydiinae&\textit{Lasconotus} sp. Erichson&3(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&Cossoninae&\textit{Cossonus} sp. Clairville&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&Curculionidae&\textit{Anthonomus} sp. Germar&1(2)&3&1(1)&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(1)&0&0&0&0&0 \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Dendroctonus brevicomis$^3$} LeConte&137(152)&10&0.01(1)&0&0&0&0.04(3.6)&0.22(3.07)&0.05(2.86)&0&0&0&0.03(1.5)&0&0.01(1) \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Dendroctonus frontalis} Zimmermann&36(48)&6&0.06(4.5)&0&0&0&0.03(1)&0.19(2)&0.17(3.33)&0&0&0&0&0.03(1)&0 \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Dendroctonus} sp. Erichson&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Dendroctonus valens} LeConte&1(15)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(15)&0&0&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Dendroctonus valens} LeConte&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Dendroctonus valens} LeConte&55(118)&6&0.02(2)&0&0&0&0&0&0&0.02(1)&0.35(4.42)&0&0.04(3.5)&0.09(4.4)&0 \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Dendroctonus valens} LeConte&1(2)&3&0&0&1(1)&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(1)&0&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Dryocetes autographus} (Ratzeburg)&3(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Dryopthorus americanus} Bedel&5(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Dryopthorus americanus} Bedel&4(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Dryopthorus americanus} Bedel&2(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Gnathotrichus materarius} Bedel&2(3)&2&0&0&0.5(2)&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Hylastes porculus} Erichson&1(1)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(1)&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Hylastes porculus} Erichson&47(16)&6&0&0&0&0&0&0.02(2)&0&0.04(1)&0.04(1)&0&0&0&0.02(1) \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Hylastes porculus} Erichson&3(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Hylobius} sp. Germar&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Ips avulsus} (Eichhoff)&239(2886)&9&0.23(2.57)&0.02(1)&0&0&0&0.16(2.03)&0.6(17.78)&0(1)&0.02(4.5)&0&0.13(1.44)&0(1)&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Ips calligraphus} (Germar)&1(36)&3&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(35)&0&1(1)&0&0&0&0 \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Ips grandicollis} (Eichhoff)&11(194)&5&0.45(17.8)&0&0.18(3)&0&0&0&0.55(16)&0&0&0&0.09(2)&0&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Ips grandicollis} (Eichhoff)&35(407)&7&0.29(2.2)&0&0&0&0&0.06(2.5)&0.26(20.44)&0.03(1)&0.37(12.92)&0&0.17(4.5)&0&0 \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Ips grandicollis} (Eichhoff)&10(189)&6&0.8(4.12)&0&0.2(3.5)&0&0&0.1(1)&0&0&0.5(21.4)&0&0.1(40)&0&0 \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Ips pini} (Say)&222(4688)&14&0.44(14.05)&0.02(1.75)&0.23(3.56)&0.07(1.75)&0.01(1.33)&0.08(2.44)&0.65(19.91)&0.02(10.8)&0.05(1.83)&0&0.21(2.07)&0.01(1)&0(1) \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Ips pini} (Say)&51(901)&11&0.33(4.76)&0&0&0.02(4)&0&0.14(2.86)&0.76(19.95)&0.02(1)&0.02(1)&0&0.08(1)&0.02(1)&0.04(1) \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Ips pini} (Say)&20(203)&7&0.3(27)&0&0.25(3.4)&0&0&0&0&0&0.25(3)&0&0.25(1.2)&0&0.1(1.5) \\
2013&AZ&&\textit{Orthotomicus caelatus} (Eichhoff)&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Pachylobius picivorus} (Germar)&15(215)&5&0&0&0.07(4)&0&0&0&0&0&0.07(1)&0.2(53.67)&0&0.07(49)&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Pityopthorus} sp. Eichhoff&2(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Rhyncolus} sp. Germar&&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Xylosandrus} sp. Reitter&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&Elateridae&\textit{Ampedus} sp. Germar&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Melanotus} sp.&1(7)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(7)&0&0&0&0 \\
2011&WI&&\textit{Platysoma cylindrica}&4(7)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(1.75)&0&0&0&0 \\
2011&WI&Tenebrionidae&\textit{Corticeus parallelus} (Melsheimer)&5(41)&6&0.4(1.5)&0&0.2(16)&0&0&0&0&0&0.8(5)&0&0.2(1)&0.2(1)&0 \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Corticeus parallelus} (Melsheimer)&1(1)&2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1(1)&0&0&0&0 \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Hymenorus} sp.&3(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&WI&&\textit{Hymenorus} sp.&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Isomira} sp. Mulsant&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&AZ&Trogossitidae&\textit{Temnocheila} sp. Westwood&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&Zopheridae&\textit{Lasconotus} sp. Erichson&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\
2013&GA&&\textit{Namunaria} sp.&1(0)&0&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&--&-- \\ \hline
&&&Total Beetle Species Carrying&--&--&9&3&6&3&3&7&7&9&12&3&9&6&5 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your formatting! I think you have given me what I need -- the rest is on me. One odd thing is that the 2013 in the first column does not appear to be complying with `\small`. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @JessePfammatter no it is small it just looks large because I set the rest of the table \tiny....

Answer (score 2):

You can have a more readable longtable (`\footnotesize`) if you allow for linebreaks from the fourth column, with the `makecell` package. Here is an attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry, amssymb, amsmath, setspace, rotating, titlesec, multirow, adjustbox, array, booktabs, threeparttable, longtable, lscape}
\geometry{verbose,letterpaper, margin=2.54cm}% a3paper

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
 >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
 l%
 <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{45}{1em}}}% no optional argument here, please!
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lt}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth} % default: 4in (rather less than \textwidth...)
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % default: \parindent
\setlength\LTright{0pt} % default: \fill
\footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\setlength\defaultaddspace{0.3ex}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{}c@{}r @{}>{\itshape}p{25mm}Xc*{6}{X}l@{\!}*{6}{X}l}%
\caption{...} \\
\textbf{Year}& \textbf{Region}& \textbf{Beetle Family}& \textbf{\upshape Beetle Species}& \rot{\textbf{Total Beetles (Mites)}}
& \rot{\textbf{Total Mite Species}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Iponemus confusus} Lindquist}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Dendrolaelaps neodisetus} (Hurlbutt)}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{D. quadrisetus} (Berlese)}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Ereynetes propescutulis} Hunter}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Paracarophaenax} sp.}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Tarsonemus} spp.$^1$}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Elattoma} sp.}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiogaster arborsignis} Woodring}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma} spp.$^2$}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma anops}}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Trichouropoda australis} Hirschmann}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Proctolaelaps} sp.}}& \rot{\textbf{Unidentified}} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\textbf{Year}& \textbf{Region}& \textbf{Beetle Family}& \textbf{\upshape Beetle Species}& \rot{\textbf{Total Beetles (Mites)}}
 & \rot{\textbf{Total Mite Species}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Iponemus confusus} Lindquist}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Dendrolaelaps neodisetus} (Hurlbutt)}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{D. quadrisetus} (Berlese)}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Ereynetes propescutulis} Hunter}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Paracarophaenax} sp.}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Tarsonemus} spp.$^1$}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Elattoma} sp.}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiogaster arborsignis} Woodring}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma} spp.$^2$}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Histiostoma anops}}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Trichouropoda australis} Hirschmann}}& \rot{\textbf{\textit{Proctolaelaps} sp.}}& \rot{\textbf{Unidentified}} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
2013 & GA & Cerambycidae & \makecell{Monochamus\\ titallator\\\textup{(Fabricius)}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & WI & & \makecell{Monochamus \\scutellatus \\\textup{(LeConte)}} & \makecell{2\\(20)} & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.5\\(20)} & 0 & 0 \\
2011 & WI & & \makecell{Rhagium \\inquisitor} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\

2013 & WI & & \makecell{Xylotrechus\\ \textup{sp. Chevrolat}} & \makecell{1\\(200)} & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \break(1) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \break(92) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{1\\(107)} \\
2013 & GA & Cleridae & \makecell{Enoclerus\\ ichneumoneus \\ \textup{(Fabricius)}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & WI & & \makecell{Enoclerus\\ nigrifrons\textup{(Say)}} & \makecell{4\\(1)} & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.25\\(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2011 & WI & & \makecell{Thanasimus\\ dubius$^4$ \textup{(Fabricius)}} & \makecell{21\\(91)} & 14 & \makecell{0.1\\(2)} & \makecell{0.14\\(3)} & 0 & \makecell{0.05\\(1)} & 0 & \makecell{0.05\\(1)} & 0 & \makecell{0.57\\(3.08)} & \makecell{0.24\\(1.8)} & \makecell{0.05\\(6)} & \makecell{0.05\\(1)} & 0 & \makecell{0.05\\(6)} \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Thanasimus\\dubius \textup{(Fabricius)}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & WI & & \makecell{Thanasimus\\dubius \textup{Fabricius}} & \makecell{17\\(131)} & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.29\\(21)} & \makecell{0.29\\(2.8)} & 0 & \makecell{0.18\\(4)} & 0 & 0 \\
2013 & GA & Colydiinae & \makecell{Lasconotus\\ \textup{sp. Erichson}} & \makecell{3\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & GA & Cossoninae & \makecell{Cossonus\\ \textup{sp. Clairville}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & WI & Curculionidae & \makecell{Anthonomus\\ \textup{sp. Germar}} & \makecell{1\\(2)} & 3 & \makecell{1\\(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{1\\(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2013 & AZ & & \makecell{Dendroctonus \\brevicomis$^3$\\ \textup{LeConte}} & \makecell{137\\(152)} & 10 & \makecell{0.01\\(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.04\\(3.6)} & \makecell{0.22\\(3.07)} & \makecell{0.05\\(2.86)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.03\\(1.5)} & 0 & \makecell{0.01\\(1)} \\
2013 & AZ & & \makecell{Dendroctonus \\frontalis\\\textup{Zimmermann}} & \makecell{36\\(48)} & 6 & \makecell{0.06\\(4.5)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.03\\(1)} & \makecell{0.19\\(2)} & \makecell{0.17\\(3.33)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.03\\(1)} & 0 \\
2013 & AZ & & \makecell{Dendroctonus\\ \textup{sp. Erichson}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & AZ & & \makecell{Dendroctonus\\valens \textup{LeConte}} & \makecell{1\\(15)} & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{1\\(15)} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Dendroctonus\\valens \textup{LeConte}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2011 & WI & & \makecell{Dendroctonus\\valens \textup{ LeConte}} & \makecell{55\\(118)} & 6 & \makecell{0.02\\(2)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.02\\(1)} & \makecell{0.35\\(4.42)} & 0 & \makecell{0.04\\(3.5)} & \makecell{0.09\\(4.4)} & 0 \\
2013 & WI & & \makecell{Dendroctonus\\valens \textup{LeConte}} & \makecell{1\\(2)} & 3 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{1\\(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{1\\(1)} & 0 & 0 \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Dryocetes\\autographus\\ \textup{(Ratzeburg)}} & \makecell{3\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2011 & WI & & \makecell{Dryopthorus\\ americanus \textup{Bedel}} & \makecell{5\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Dryopthorus\\ americanus \textup{Bedel}} & \makecell{4\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & WI & & \makecell{Dryopthorus\\ americanus \textup{Bedel}} & \makecell{2\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Gnathotrichus\\ materarius \textup{Bedel}} & \makecell{2\\(3)} & 2 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.5\\(2)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2013 & AZ & & \makecell{Hylastes porculus\\ \textup{Erichson}} & \makecell{1\\(1)} & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{1\\(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Hylastes porculus\\ \textup{Erichson}} & \makecell{47\\(16)} & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.02\\(2)} & 0 & \makecell{0.04\\(1)} & \makecell{0.04\\(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.02\\(1)} \\
2011 & WI & & \makecell{Hylastes porculus\\\textup{ Erichson}} & \makecell{3\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Hylobius\\ \textup{sp. Germar}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Ips avulsus\\ \textup{(Eichhoff)}} & \makecell{239\\(2886)} & 9 & \makecell{0.23\\(2.57)} & \makecell{0.02\\(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.16\\(2.03)} & \makecell{0.6\\(17.78)} & \makecell{0\\(1)} & \makecell{0.02\\(4.5)} & 0 & \makecell{0.13\\(1.44)} & \makecell{0\\(1)} & 0 \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Ips calligraphus\\ \textup{(Germar)}} & \makecell{1\\(36)} & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{1\\(35)} & 0 & \makecell{1\\(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2013 & AZ & & \makecell{Ips grandicollis\\ \textup{(Eichhoff)}} & \makecell{11\\(194)} & 5 & \makecell{0.45\\(17.8)} & 0 & \makecell{0.18\\(3)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.55\\(16)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.09\\(2)} & 0 & 0 \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Ips grandicollis\\ \textup{(Eichhoff)}} & \makecell{35\\(407)} & 7 & \makecell{0.29\\(2.2)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.06\\(2.5)} & \makecell{0.26\\(20.44)} & \makecell{0.03\\(1)} & \makecell{0.37\\(12.92)} & 0 & \makecell{0.17\\(4.5)} & 0 & 0 \\
2013 & WI & & \makecell{Ips grandicollis\\ \textup{(Eichhoff)}} & \makecell{10\\(189)} & 6 & \makecell{0.8\\(4.12)} & 0 & \makecell{0.2\\(3.5)} & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.1\\(1)} & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.5\\(21.4)} & 0 & \makecell{0.1\\(40)} & 0 & 0 \\
2013 & AZ & & \makecell{Ips pini\\ \textup{(Say)}} & \makecell{222\\(4688)} & 14 & \makecell{0.44\\(14.05)} & \makecell{0.02\\(1.75)} & \makecell{0.23\\(3.56)} & \makecell{0.07\\(1.75)} & \makecell{0.01\\(1.33)} & \makecell{0.08\\(2.44)} & \makecell{0.65\\(19.91)} & \makecell{0.02\\(10.8)} & \makecell{0.05\\(1.83)} & 0 & \makecell{0.21\\(2.07)} & \makecell{0.01\\(1)} & \makecell{0\\(1)} \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Ips pini\\ \textup{(Say)}} & \makecell{51\\(901)} & 11 & \makecell{0.33\\(4.76)} & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.02\\(4)} & 0 & \makecell{0.14\\(2.86)} & \makecell{0.76\\(19.95)} & \makecell{0.02\\(1)} & \makecell{0.02\\(1)} & 0 & \makecell{0.08\\(1)} & \makecell{0.02\\(1)} & \makecell{0.04\\(1)} \\
2013 & WI & & \makecell{Ips pini\\ \textup{(Say)}} & \makecell{20\\(203)} & 7 & \makecell{0.3\\(27)} & 0 & \makecell{0.25\\(3.4)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.25\\(3)} & 0 & \makecell{0.25\\(1.2)} & 0 & \makecell{0.1\\(1.5)} \\
2013 & AZ & & \makecell{Orthotomicus\\ caelatus\textup{(Eichhoff)}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Pachylobius\\ picivorus \textup{(Germar)}} & \makecell{15\\(215)} & 5 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.07\\(4)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.07\\(1)} & \makecell{0.2\\(53.67)} & 0 & \makecell{0.07\\(49)} & 0 \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Pityopthorus\\ \textup{sp. Eichhoff}} & \makecell{2\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & WI & & \makecell{Rhyncolus\\ \textup{sp. Germar}} & & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Xylosandrus\\ \textup{sp. Reitter}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & WI & Elateridae & \makecell{Ampedus\\ \textup{sp. Germar}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & WI & & \makecell{Melanotus\\ \textup{sp.}} & \makecell{1\\(7)} & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{1\\(7)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2011 & WI & & \makecell{Platysoma \\cylindrica} & \makecell{4\\(7)} & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{1\\(1.75)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2011 & WI & Tenebrionidae & \makecell{Corticeus parallelus\\ \textup{(Melsheimer)}} & \makecell{5\\(41)} & 6 & \makecell{0.4\\(1.5)} & 0 & \makecell{0.2\\(16)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{0.8\\(5)} & 0 & \makecell{0.2\\(1)} & \makecell{0.2\\(1)} & 0 \\
2013 & WI & & \makecell{Corticeus parallelus\\ \textup{(Melsheimer})} & \makecell{1\\(1)} & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \makecell{1\\(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Hymenorus\\ \textup{sp.}} & \makecell{3\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & WI & & \makecell{Hymenorus\\ \textup{sp.}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Isomira\\ \textup{sp. Mulsant}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & AZ & Trogossitidae & \makecell{Temnocheila\\ \textup{sp. Westwood}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & GA & Zopheridae & \makecell{Lasconotus\\ \textup{sp. Erichson}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
2013 & GA & & \makecell{Namunaria\\ \textup{sp.}} & \makecell{1\\(0)} & 0 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\ \midrule
 & & &\makecell{\upshape Total Beetle\\\upshape Species Carrying} & -- & -- & 9 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 12 & 3 & 9 & 6 & 5
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

And 3 of the pages (on 6):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! Something I had done in previous versions of this table in word but was not quite sure how to approach it. Thanks! Did you do this all by hand or did you use some sort of macro to fill in all the extra formatting?

Comment: There was a basic idea: it was necessary to have line breaks in cells for which this made sense. Even landscape A3 paper was somewhat tight with `\normalsize`. I often use the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in ‘normal’ cells (l, r, c), and also a common formatting and control oover the vertical and horizontal alignment.  The rest of the job was a matter of trials and errors.